# Why is this home page un-editable in SharePoint 365?

Tags: sharepoint-online

We've recently started working with Office 365 at work. Our systems admin developed a team for us and I set up an associated team website. Today I tried to edit the home page for the website and got an error: "[Department Director] is currently editing this page. Please try again later." 
[image]

At the time, the director didn't even have a browser open. I don't think she's aware this site exists. What might be causing her name to pop up and prevent me from editing? Is this something I (not the owner of the group) can fix?

Comment: Actually it appears that this is a duplicate and has been successfully answered: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/5702/78244 Can someone VTC as duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

I believe she also have full rights to edit the site. She might have clicked some hyperlink from email or word document and have done something.

**To solve this problem:**

if you have sharepoint designer installed on your machine. You could open this site and select the relevant page.

1. On the info or right click select Discard Check out

or you could something like below

1. Once you open the site > Click All Files > select the document library
2. Right click and Discard checkout.

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: You don't need SPD for this. You can override checkout from the browser if you're a site owner.

Comment: Yes Agreed. I should have mentioned that also.

Comment: @RagavanRajan could you add those instructions please?